# Program not waiting for Timer to finish before continuing its loop

Tags: java, multithreading, time, sleep

I have the following code that runs whenever you click the Start button on my program. I have denoted via comments where I want the timer to go, problem is, when I do `thread.sleep(time)` it freezes my program! So, I was wondering if someoen could just simply add atimer to my code so it runs the first bit, waits, then runs it again based on bumpNum.

Code:

```
public class startReplyButtonListener implements ActionListener{


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){

            int length = textAreaReplyMessage.getText().length();
            int remLen = 400 - length;

            String strHTML = neo.get("http://www.neopets.com/neoboards/topic.phtml?topic=" + txtTopicID.getText());
            /*strHTML = neo.post("/neoboards/process_topic.phtml?", new String[][] {{"boardType", "topic_id", "board_id", "message", "next", "remLen"}, {"reply", txtTopicID.getText(), "4", textAreaReplyMessage.getText() , "1", ((Integer)remLen).toString()}});

            if(strHTML.contains("No topic with ID")){
                txtLog.append("Invalid Topic ID! \n");
            }
            else{
                txtLog.append("Bumped Topic ID " + txtTopicID.getText() + "\n");
            }
            */
            System.out.println(strHTML);
            bumpNum = 5;
            wait = Integer.parseInt(textWait1.getText()) * 1000; //converting to miliseconds

            int i=1;
            do{
                strHTML = neo.post("/neoboards/process_topic.phtml?", new String[][] {{"boardType", "topic_id", "board_id", "message", "next", "remLen"}, {"reply", txtTopicID.getText(), "4", textAreaReplyMessage.getText() , "1", ((Integer)remLen).toString()}});

                txtLog.append("Board Bumped. Waiting "+ ((Integer)(wait/1000)).toString() +" Seconds..." + "\n");

                //ADD TIMER HERE
                i++;



            }while(i <= bumpNum);

        }

        }
```

What I wish to accomplish:

User indicates how many times they want to "post"(indicated by bumpNum), the loop will first, post once:

```
strHTML = neo.post("/neoboards/process_topic.phtml?", new String[][] {{"boardType", "topic_id", "board_id", "message", "next", "remLen"}, {"reply", txtTopicID.getText(), "4", textAreaReplyMessage.getText() , "1", ((Integer)remLen).toString()}});
```

Then:
Based on users input, it will wait for however many seconds(txtWait1) and THEN repeat the posting code above until it has reached bumpNum.

And it will update txtLog with the following EACH TIME it bumps(so the program cannot be frozen):

```
txtLog.append("Board Bumped. Waiting "+ ((Integer)(wait/1000)).toString() +" Seconds..." + "\n");
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?  If you just want to sleep for 3 seconds after each loop iteration, you don't need a thread, just sleep right there, in the loop.  You don't need to be "in a thread" to invoke Thread.sleep(1000);

Comment: I want it to go through the loop once, wait the time indicated by the wait variable, then repeat until the loop has reached its goal amount of run-throughs. When I do Thread.sleep, the program freezes. I am doing this all in the GUI.java class

Comment: Then just do all of it in a single worker thread and do normal sleep in that thread?  Or think about using Swing Timers http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

Comment: Read the tutorial on how to use a Swing Timer and try to use it in place of your while loop.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Don't think of code because you are confused and we can't figure out what you are trying to do.  What do you ant your program to do when it reaches "ADD TIMER HERE"?

Comment: I have edited OP with my exact wishes :) Thanks for all the help, btw.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll just give up on this then. Thanks for you help. I'll close this.

Comment: One more thing.  Whenever you ask a question on SO you'll need to provide some idea that you've done work but don't think of it as code.  Say that you have the GUI portion, etc..

Comment: The bottom line for most your problems is that you shoudn't call `Thread.sleep(...)` on the Swing thread. There are better ways to do this sort of thing either with SwingWorker, other background Threads, or a Swing Timer, and which to choose will all depend on the details of the overall problem you are trying to solve, not so much your code attempt. Sorry but this yours is a terrible question which is very incomplete and confusing. In the future you will want to spend more time clarifying exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

Sigh.  Ok, now I understand.  I don't know the answer.  You are talking about drawing a GUI element.  I suspect you want to fork a thread to do a job and then show the GUI display that you are waiting for it.  You need to wait for the thread to finish (see my `join` code below) all of the time having the GUI element refresh UNTIL it finishes when you display some result.

This depends more on the GUI code than sleep/timer.  I would start a new question now and explain !!!NOT WITH CODE!!! but with pseudo code from 1000 foot view what you want.  Something like:

> I am trying to fork a thread that runs in the background in [Swing/Android/etc].  I want to display to the user that the thread has been forked, I want the user interface to wait for the thread without freezing, and then I want the user interface to `join` with the thread and display the results.

Think about the problem like we have to think of it.  Anticipate questions that we will ask.  Figure out what we don't and can't know about your environment.

Best of luck.

**Edit:**

If you are just trying to call sleep then you don't need to fork a thread for that.  All you need to do in your code is:

```
  try {
      Thread.sleep(waitingTime);
      System.out.println(waitingTime);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

This will pause the current thread (which could be the main thread) for waitingTime milliseconds.

---

So you are forking 3 threads very quickly which I guess you don't want to do.  If you are  trying to wait for each thread to finish then you will have to do something like:

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(new Counter(wait));
 thread.start();
 thread.join();
```

Couple of other comments:

- It is considered bad form to start a thread in the constructor of a class: `new Thread(this).start();`
- You are creating 2 thread objects inside of your Runnable.  You should just create one *outside* of your `Runnable`.  See above.

  ```
  Thread myCounter = new Thread(this);  << #1
  public Counter(int waitingTime) {
     new Thread(this).start();          << #2
  }
  ```
- I would not initialize `waitingTime = 0;` when defined *and* initialize it in the constructor.  This is confusing.  Remove the `= 0`.

  ```
      int waitingTime;                    << remove the =0 here
      public Counter(int waitingTime) {
         this.waitingTime = waitingTime;
  ```
- When you catch `InterruptedException`, be sure to handle it right.  A good pattern is to reset the interrupt flag and/or quit the thread:

  ```
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      // resets the interrupt flag cleared by catching the exception
      Thread.currentThread.interrupt();
      // or stops the thread immediately
      return;
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am just learning Java, so it's all quite confusing to me. I'll post my full code for the button in the GUI above. in my OP.

Comment: @user1176922 I've edited my answer in case you are just trying to pause for a second.

Comment: The code at the top of your post. And for 31 seconds each time. With your code, I press the "start button", it does the action once, pauses for 31 seconds.....does not repeat the action....pauses for 31 seconds....does not repeat the action....pauses 31 seconds. Then unfreezes AND THEN the logg is added.

Comment: I edited my OP with my Main goal for this. It is at the bottom of OP

Comment: Ok.  I think I see what is going on @user1176922.  You expect to see the "Waiting" message.  You won't because this renders AFTER the sleep.  If you want your program to sleep then it will "freeze" i.e. sleep.  If you want it to sleep in a thread then it's not going to wait at all.  Please take a sleep back and edit your question and tell us what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Okay, yes! that is the problem! I'll edit my OP with exactly what I wish to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You're starting a new thread each time through the loop.  Rather than creating a new thread in the constructor, move the `do/while` loop into a normal method rather than the run method of a new thread.  What you're doing is spawning a new thread that does in fact sleep, but it's not the thread that's executing the loop so that thread just continues as normal.